# Trying to download an image from a web url but receive IOException error HTTP Resoponse code 403 (Java)

Tags: java

Here is the code I'm trying to use to download my image

```
package practice;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.net.URL;

public class SaveImageFromUrl {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        String imageUrl = "http://hellocomic.com/img/magazines/action-comics/action-comics-15/Action_15_TheGroup_001.jpg";
        String destinationFile = "/Users/danielflores/Desktop/Comics/image.jpg";

        saveImage(imageUrl, destinationFile);
    }

    public static void saveImage(String imageUrl, String destinationFile) throws IOException {
        URL url = new URL(imageUrl);
        InputStream is = url.openStream();
        OutputStream os = new FileOutputStream(destinationFile);

        byte[] b = new byte[2048];
        int length;

        while ((length = is.read(b)) != -1) {
            os.write(b, 0, length);
        }

        is.close();
        os.close();
    }

}
```

but I keep receiving a "Server returned HTTP response code: 403 for URL:" message

**NOTE:** I don't really understand what this code means I got it from another website I'm just trying to download this image using java so I can use a for loop to download multiple images from this site.

Comment: 403 is the Forbidden HTTP status code.
If you want more details about HTTP status codes refer to the following link.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes,  HTTP 403


  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_403

Answer (score 1, accepted):

User-Agent needs to be included in the request.

```
public static void saveImage(String imageUrl, String destinationFile) throws IOException {
                URL url = new URL(imageUrl);
                HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                conn.setRequestMethod("GET");
                conn.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0");
    //          System.out.println(openConnection.getContentLength());
                InputStream is = conn.getInputStream();
                OutputStream os = new FileOutputStream(destinationFile);

                byte[] b = new byte[2048];
                int length;

                while ((length = is.read(b)) != -1) {
                    os.write(b, 0, length);
                }

                is.close();
                os.close();
            }
```

A web server may return a 403 Forbidden HTTP status code in response to a request from a client for a web page or resource to indicate that the server can be reached and understood the request, but refuses to take any further action.

Wikipedia - [HTTP 403](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_403)

Comment: THANK YOU SO MUCH YOU ARE SUCH A LIFE SAVER

Answer (score 0):

Another example if you like

```
public static void saveImage(String imageUrl, String destinationFile) throws IOException {
    URL url = new URL(imageUrl);
    HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

    conn.setRequestMethod("GET");
    conn.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0");
    int contentLength = conn.getContentLength();

    int numberofBytesRead = 0;
    InputStream is = new BufferedInputStream(conn.getInputStream());
    OutputStream os = new FileOutputStream(destinationFile);

    byte[] data = new byte[contentLength];
    int offset = 0, bytesRead = 0;
    while (offset < contentLength) {
        bytesRead = is.read(data, offset, (data.length - offset));

        if (bytesRead == -1) break;
        offset += bytesRead;
        numberofBytesRead += bytesRead;
    }

    os.write(data); 
    is.close();
    os.close();
}
```